# Storing pills together

Tags: medications

How long can I store Magnesium Chloride tablets with my other medications? I use a one-week pill organizer and wonder if the water absorbing properties of the magnesium are a concern within  that timeframe. I have been storing the magnesium separately from the rest but would like to have them all in one compartment if this is not an issue. Thank you.

Comment: Strongly related: [Does keeping different types of medications in one pill bottle affect their quality?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/does-keeping-different-types-of-medications-in-one-pill-bottle-affect-their-qual?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Prescription drugs always have a label with their expiration date.  That date is only valid if you keep the tablets/pills/solution in their original containers. Once you remove them, they are exposed to air humidity and they deteriorate quicker. Therefore, your physician wouldn't advise you to remove the pills from their original package and store them somewhere else.